# Como saber se um stdClass está vazio?

Tags: php, stdclass

No PHP, para verificar se um `array` está vazio podemos utilizar a função (ou construtor da linguagem) `empty`.

Assim:

```
$a = array();

$b = array(1, 2);

var_dump(empty($a), empty($b)); // Imprime: bool(true), bool(false)
```

Porém o mesmo não acontece com `stdClass`.

```
$a = (object) array();

$b = (object)array('nome' => 'wallace');

$c = new stdClass(); // A mesma coisa que $a

var_dump(empty($a), empty($b), empty($c)); // Imprime: bool(false), bool(false), bool(false)
```

Veja no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/n53lIP)

Então qual é a maneira de se saber que um objeto `stdClass` está vazio ou não em PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar a função `get_object_vars`, para retornar as propriedades do `stdClass` num `array`. Em seguida, você poderia utilizar a função  `count` ou `empty`, para saber se está vazio ou não.

Exemplo:

```
$object = new stdClass;

count(get_object_vars($object)) == 0;// Imprime: bool(true)

$array = get_object_vars($object);

var_dump(empty($array)); // Imprime: bool(true);
```

Comment: Tiago, creio que você é novo no stackoverlow. VocÊ deveria utilizar os comentários para esse tipo de coisas. Isso geralmente é um chamativo para votos negativos, mas para te ajudar, vou editar a sua respostas, para você como ela poderia melhorar, ok?

Comment: Isso deve ser postado nos comentários. Quando você vai apresentar uma hipótese, você usa os comentários. Quando vai apresentar uma solução concreta, você usa a resposta.

Comment: _Não tenhas pressa de responder, apressa-te apenas em ajudar_.

Comment: Acho que a gente já pode remover essa penca de comentários daqui

Comment: @WallaceMaxters apenas para eu saber, você que removeria tudo os comentários neste caso? Fiquei na dúvida se estava pedindo aprovação para fazê-lo, ou se cada um tem que apagar seu comentário para limpar, valeu!

Comment: É que o assunto fugiu do contexto da pergunta.Isso não é recomendado

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para um auxílio extra, caso alguém precise, poderíamos fazer isso utilizando um loop em cima do `stdClass`. Se entrar no `foreach` é porque é um objeto com propriedades. Se não, está vazio.

Veja:

```
function is_empty_object(stdClass $object)
{

    foreach($object as $value) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Sei que faz muito tempo, mas você pode usar a função **get_object_vars** e colocar uma exclamação na sua frente e, desta forma, o retorno será um *boolean*.

```
$data= new stdClass;

var_dump(!get_object_vars($data)); # bool(true)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).